# Karbon A9+ System space and Internal Storage

Tags: internal-storage, karbonn-a9

1. I have recently moved from iPhone 3G(3 years) to Karbon A9+(ICS). While my mobile is showing GBs of space available, I frequently get Low System space warning. I had then added a 8 GB external SD card but to no avail. Coming from an iPhone background, this was confusing....if I have tonnes of space why am I getting such notifications?
2. On System Setting under Storage,its displays "Total space 581 MB" out of which 89 MB is available. Internal Storage is 2.57 GB out which 2.56 GB is available. While on other mobiles of other brands, I dont see the distinction between System space and Internal Storage. Which this discrepancies and what are the consequences?
3. I have rooted my device...Is there some method where I can increase my system space to include the Internal Storage which is lying almost completely un-utilized?

Answer (score 0):

Just use DS super App2SD lite app, which gives you to system apps to your memory card
And this app work in only rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

You can partition your external SD card to ext4 and then use Link2SD to move large apps to this partition along with their internal data, .odex, dalvik cache. Make sure both partitions are set as "Primary"

They'll function in a normal manner after moving. Only remember that removing the sd card will crash all those apps so do not move important apps.

Examples:
Do move: Games, News feeds, Photoshop
Don't move: Google Play Services, Google Play store, keyboards